# Where can I find the text "You must enable cookies to use WordPress." On wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for the text "ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress." Does anyone know what file holds this string? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is the Browser, not wordpress? if wordpress can't set `$_COOKIE[ TEST_COOKIE ]` then you get this issue

Comment: The point is I want it to display my site name, not wordpress. I'm not looking for a solution to the error. lol

Comment: oh.. so you are, then just search the code for a snippet of the text... `Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser` is enough to locate it eg `app/wp-login.php`

Comment: Yep. Found it. Thanks!